# C# Object Modeling decision

Tags: c#, .net, object, object-model

I have a `[ConfidentialInfo]` object that is sent as input over the wire for further processing.

```
ConfidentialInfo
{
  confidentialInfo 1,
  confidentialInfo 2,
  confidentialInfo 3
}
```

I need to send back some derived values,  after processing this input,  as an object. Now, these values also bear close affinity to being part of the original input object.

```
ConfidentialInfo
{ 
 outputNotSoConfidentialInfo 1,
  outputNotSoConfidentialInfo 2
}
```

Should I model both the input and output together as one object - `[ConfidentialInfo]` or end up modeling 2 different objects ---- `[ConfidentialInfoInput]` and `[ConfidentialInfoOutput]`?

**[Update and Elaboration] :** My dilemma is:

If they are modeled as one which makes absolute sense btw, there is a need to differentiate it. There is no immediate grasp of what is input and output.

If they are modeled separate...differentiation is explicit but cohesiveness is gone. And there are equality checks and other comparisons that come into place to ensure that output was indeed derived from given input.

What is the sensible way to proceed?

Comment: @HighCore elaboration please?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm asking from you.

Comment: @HighCore elaborated.

Comment: could you further explain about the close affinity between the input and output objects?

Comment: what does the application gain by the two being in the same class?  do you ever need to check that output x really came from input y?  even so, it seems like you could model them separately and then relate them in some other fashion if you needed to...

Comment: This is like pulling teeth.  What elements do the two classes have that are exactly the same?

Comment: @SteveWellens `ConfidentialInfo1`with a few characters zeroed out can be considered `notSoConfidentialInfo1`. (just applying a simple business rule here for clarity)

Comment: Maybe you could give a sample of data in the two classes.

Answer (score 3):

Only you, the author of the code, know enough to make this call. To start you thinking down the right path, first consider the [SOLID single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by evaluating the impact of a small change in requirements to the hypothetical classes. If a small change requires updates in both classes then you have a tight coupling and should consider some form of common code; either as an Interface, or a common base class. If a small change would be likely only affect one of the two instances, then that is an argument for separation at some level.

Here are some more thought exercises to consider: the methods each class needs to support.

Case for 2 instances of a single class:

If both the inbound and outbound instances need to have the same methods, with the same code in them, then they should be instances of the same class with a flag like `IsConfidential` to trigger a (very, very) small change in behavior.

Case for 2 different classes:

If there is very little-to-no overlap in the methods required by each instance, then they should have two different base classes, but perhaps they can implement a common Interface so they have property type alignment.

Case for 2 classes from a shared base class

Both instances need to have the same methods, like a `Validate()` or `Send()`, but they need different implementations of those methods, then they should either have a base class which defines the commonalities and a base implementation, or just implement an interface which has those method signatures specified

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make ConfidentialInfo as abstract class, so the [ConfidentialInfoInput] and [ConfidentialInfoOutput] classes will inherit from it.